# Administration Theme switches to front-end theme

Tags: 7

I am using administration theme "Seven".

When I clear cache or I work with some module and then I save its settings, the administration theme *switches* to front-end theme.

If i reload browsers current page, then the front-end theme *switches* back to the admin theme.

Is there any setting that can fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the admin theme on the overlay?

Comment: Overlay module disabled, it happens in multilingual sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overlay does not work with prefixed URL paths.
http://drupal.org/node/1075096